# defining of specific selector of component at run time in angular2

Tags: angular

guys, I'm new to angular, and here's my question.Is there a way to create a component inside of certain selector at runtime, for example by sending a ref to element that will be hosting my component as a parameter to function that creates component. Right now I have following code whose create button adds component inside `<dynamic-component>`, but there is also ngfor, so after I will get several `<dynamic-component>`s, how can I specify only one place to add this component? Any help, who understood my problem.

```
<div *ngFor="let Mytask of tasks">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr *ngIf="!Mytask.ParentTaskId"(click)="setParentTask(new,Mytask)"
                (dblclick)="showEditForTask(Mytask)">
                <td>{{Mytask.Title}}</td>
                <td>{{Mytask.StartTime}}</td>
                <td>{{Mytask.FinishTime}}</td>
                <td>{{Mytask.States.State}}</td>
                <td> <button (click)="createTaskComponent(Mytask)">Create</button><td>
         </tr>
         <tr #new>
         <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</div>
```

function inside my component

```js
componentData:any = null;

  createTaskComponent(task:Tasks){
    this.getMyChildren(task);
    this.componentData = {
      component: TaskWorldComponent,
      inputs: {
        tasks: this.children
      }
    };
  }
```

code that inserts component is taken from plunker

```
import {Component, Input, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ReflectiveInjector, 
          ComponentFactoryResolver} from '@angular/core';
import TaskWorldComponent from './task-world-component';


@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  entryComponents: [TaskWorldComponent], 
  template: `
    <div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>
  `,
})
export default class DynamicComponent {
  currentComponent:any = null;

  @ViewChild('dynamicComponentContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @Input() set componentData(data: {component: any, inputs: any }) {
    if (!data) {
      return;
    }
    let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};});
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector);
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);
    let component = factory.create(injector);
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);
    if (this.currentComponent) {
      this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
  }

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }
}
```

and component to add

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { AspNetUsers,Projects,AspNetRoles,AspNetUserClaims,AspNetUserLogins,Tasks,States} from './shared/classes';


@Component({
  selector: 'task-world',
  template: `
     <div *ngFor="let Mytask of tasks">
                        <thead></thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{Mytask.Title}}</td>
                                <td>{{Mytask.StartTime}}</td>
                                <td>{{Mytask.FinishTime}}</td>
                                <td>{{Mytask.States.State}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>    
                    </div>
                    <button (click)="createTaskComponent()">Create Task</button>
                    <dynamic-component [componentData]="componentData"></dynamic-component>
  `,
})
export default class TaskWorldComponent {
  tasks:Tasks[] = [];

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.tasks = this.injector.get('tasks');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not email, please don't prefix all your sentences with >.